# Finding items for building new facilities at base

Tags: state-of-decay

I'm trying to build a garden, but now they tell me I need a rake.
There's a magnifying glass on my map, that seems to say there's a rake there, but it's in the middle of nowhere. There's nothing there.
Am I supposed to do something special there?

While there, looking for the rake, they call me again, and say we need kitchen hinges. 
Again, a magnifying glass shows, in the middle of nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you move your cursor over the magnifying glass little almost invisible question marks will show up around your map...the things you need are in one of those question marked buildings.